# Access camera at remote location on iphone

Tags: live-streaming, ip-camera

I am creating an app in which i have to access four cameras installed at different locations on my iPhone. After googling for some time i found that it will be done with http live streaming but i am confused at all about from where to proceed.

I would appreciate any help in the right direction.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Note, you can not get access your cams without static ip on cams. You can use vpn server, and connect cams and iphone(I dont know exactly about connecting iphone to VPN) to this server, and make routes between device. So, here you can perform some operations on server